# What are ARG and LABEL in a Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that starts out...

```
FROM some.artifactory.example.com/openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ARG version
LABEL version=$version
...
```

I'd like to know what 'version' and '$version' are and what their utility is as the values to ARG and LABEL respectively. Like does `ARG version` somehow pull some value "in scope" and then `LABEL version=$version` use that...to what end? Nowhere else in the Dockerfile in question do I see any mention of version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `LABEL` is a piece of metadata on an image. You can add any `key=val` as a LABEL.

An `ARG` is something you can pass at build time, to the builder. You can then use the value in your Dockerfile during the build (but it is no longer available at runtime; so unless you somehow persist the value into the image itself, the container will have no idea what the value was).

```
docker build --build-arg version=1.2.3
```

Based on this Dockerfile, it looks like the author wanted to pass a version number at build time, and persist that in the metadata. They used the `ARG` (and `--build-arg`) to pass in the value, and they used the `LABEL` to store it in the resulting image, as metadata.

In other words, this appears to be some sort of organization / bookkeeping for the image, but it has no effect on the image's contents or runtime characteristics.